# Can anyone help debug an issue I have with this program

Tags: c#, debugging

For some reason the parallel arrays that I created wouldn't correspond with each other. When I would type in the size of a pizza it would output the first variable in the array. Thank you!

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Pizza_Prices_2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            char[] PizzaSizes = new char[] { 'S', 'M', 'L', 'X' };
            double[] PizzaPrices = new double[] { 6.99, 8.99, 12.50, 15.00 };
            int index = 0, NumOfPizzas = 0;
            double Discount = 0.0, TotalPizzaPrice = 0.0;
            string PizzaSizeAsString, NumOfPIzzasAsString;
            char PizzaSizeChar;
            Console.Write("What pizza size do you want? ");
            PizzaSizeAsString = Console.ReadLine();
            PizzaSizeChar = Convert.ToChar(PizzaSizeAsString);
            Console.Write("How many pizzas do you want");
            NumOfPIzzasAsString = Console.ReadLine();
            NumOfPizzas = Convert.ToInt32(NumOfPIzzasAsString);
            foreach (char PizzaSize in PizzaSizes)

                if (PizzaSize == PizzaSizeChar)
                {
                        TotalPizzaPrice = (PizzaPrices[index] * NumOfPizzas);
                        Console.WriteLine("Your {0} pizza would normally be {1}",      PizzaSize, PizzaPrices[index].ToString("C"));
                        Console.WriteLine("Your total would {0}", TotalPizzaPrice.ToString("C"));
                }
            if (NumOfPizzas == 2)
            {
                Discount = 0.10;
                Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
                Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
            }
            if (NumOfPizzas == 3 || NumOfPizzas == 4)
            {
                Discount = 0.15;
                Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
                Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
            }

            if (NumOfPizzas >= 5)
            {
                Discount = 0.20;


                Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
                Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
            }




        }
    }
}
```

I really don't know what the issue is. It would be really helpful if someone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies on this line

```
TotalPizzaPrice = (PizzaPrices[index] * NumOfPizzas);
```

You can see you access `PizzaPrices` array at `index`. The value of `index` is always `0` because it never set to another value. The quick fix is increment the value of `index` for each iteration.

```
foreach (char PizzaSize in PizzaSizes)
{
    if (PizzaSize == PizzaSizeChar)
    {
        TotalPizzaPrice = (PizzaPrices[index] * NumOfPizzas);
        Console.WriteLine("Your {0} pizza would normally be {1}", PizzaSize, PizzaPrices[index].ToString("C"));
        Console.WriteLine("Your total would {0}", TotalPizzaPrice.ToString("C"));
    }

    index++;
}
```

---

Although it will be better if you can use `Dictionary` for the prices and separate business method for getting the discount so you don't repeat much code.

```
class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<char, double> Prices = new Dictionary<char, double>
        {
            {'S', 6.99},
            {'M', 8.99},
            {'L', 12.50},
            {'X', 15}
        };

        int NumOfPizzas = 0;
        double Discount = 0.0, TotalPizzaPrice = 0.0;
        string PizzaSizeAsString, NumOfPIzzasAsString;

        char PizzaSizeChar;

        Console.Write("What pizza size do you want? ");
        PizzaSizeAsString = Console.ReadLine();
        PizzaSizeChar = Convert.ToChar(PizzaSizeAsString);

        Console.Write("How many pizzas do you want");
        NumOfPIzzasAsString = Console.ReadLine();
        NumOfPizzas = Convert.ToInt32(NumOfPIzzasAsString);

        TotalPizzaPrice = Prices[PizzaSizeChar] * NumOfPizzas;
        Console.WriteLine("Your {0} pizza would normally be {1}", PizzaSizeChar, Prices[PizzaSizeChar]);
        Console.WriteLine("Your total would {0}", TotalPizzaPrice.ToString("C"));

        Discount = GetDiscount(NumOfPizzas);
        if (Discount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
            Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
        }   
    }

    public double GetDiscount(int amount)
    {
        if(amount == 2) return 0.1;
        if(amount == 3 || amount == 4) return 0.15;
        if(amount >= 5) return 0.2;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use a `Dictionary<char,double>` instead for the combination of a `char[]` and a `double[]`, so that you can easily deal with the user inputs: Take a look into the code below:

```
Dictionary<char, double> pizzaPrices = new Dictionary<char, double>(){
{ 'S', 6.99},{ 'M', 8.99},{ 'L', 12.50},{ 'X', 15.00}};

int NumOfPizzas = 0;
double Discount = 0.0, TotalPizzaPrice = 0.0;     
char PizzaSizeChar;
Console.Write("What pizza size do you want? ");        
PizzaSizeChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; // Gives you the input character
if (pizzaPrices.ContainsKey(PizzaSizeChar))
{
    Console.Write("How many pizzas do you want");
    NumOfPizzas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // pizzaPrices[PizzaSizeChar] gives you the price of that char
    TotalPizzaPrice = pizzaPrices[PizzaSizeChar] * NumOfPizzas;

    Console.WriteLine("Your {0} pizza would normally be {1}", PizzaSizeChar, pizzaPrices[PizzaSizeChar].ToString("C"));
    Console.WriteLine("Your total would {0}", TotalPizzaPrice.ToString("C"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if this is fine

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    char[] PizzaSizes = new char[] { 'S', 'M', 'L', 'X' };
    double[] PizzaPrices = new double[] { 6.99, 8.99, 12.50, 15.00 };
    int index = 0, NumOfPizzas = 0;
    double Discount = 0.0, TotalPizzaPrice = 0.0;
    string PizzaSizeAsString, NumOfPIzzasAsString;
    char PizzaSizeChar;
    Console.Write("What pizza size do you want? ");
    PizzaSizeAsString = Console.ReadLine();
    PizzaSizeChar = Convert.ToChar(PizzaSizeAsString);
    index =   Array.IndexOf(PizzaSizes, PizzaSizeChar);
    Console.Write("How many pizzas do you want");
    NumOfPIzzasAsString = Console.ReadLine();
    NumOfPizzas = Convert.ToInt32(NumOfPIzzasAsString);
    foreach (char PizzaSize in PizzaSizes)

        if (PizzaSize == PizzaSizeChar)
        {
                TotalPizzaPrice = (PizzaPrices[index] * NumOfPizzas);
                Console.WriteLine("Your {0} pizza would normally be {1}",      PizzaSize, PizzaPrices[index].ToString("C"));
                Console.WriteLine("Your total would {0}", TotalPizzaPrice.ToString("C"));
        }
    if (NumOfPizzas == 2)
    {
        Discount = 0.10;
        Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
        Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
    }
    if (NumOfPizzas == 3 || NumOfPizzas == 4)
    {
        Discount = 0.15;
        Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
        Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
    }

    if (NumOfPizzas >= 5)
    {
        Discount = 0.20;


        Console.WriteLine("Because you ordered {1} pizzas, your discount is {0}", Discount.ToString("P1"), NumOfPizzas);
        Console.WriteLine("For a final total of {0}", (TotalPizzaPrice * (1 - Discount)).ToString("C"));
    }
    }
```

I only set value of index like this

```
index =   Array.IndexOf(PizzaSizes, PizzaSizeChar);
```